# Obtener todos los datos de UNA COLUMNA COMPLETA

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, php7

hola necesito obtener todos los datos de la columna "producto" en un array pero todos los ejemplos que busco toman la fila completa y eso no me sirve...he buscado soluciones con jquery y javascript nada de lo que veo me sirve. Gracias de antemano. Basicamente lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se pulse en un boton , que al cargar está oculto, cargue toda la columna "PRODUCTOS" en un array, que luego pueda enviar a otro archivo .php que estoy preparando. [image: adjunto una imagen de mi tabla]

AQUÍ MI CÓDIGO

```
<table class="table table-bordered col-6" id="miTabla">
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-info text-center">
                    <th scope="col">PRODUCTO</th>
                    <th scope="col">PRECIO</th>
                    <th scope="col">CANTIDAD</th>
                    <th scope="col">SUBTOTAL</th>                        
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])) {

                    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($compras) - 1; $i++) {

                        if ($compras[$i] != NULL) {
                            ?>
                            <tr class="text-center selected" id="fila<?php echo $cont++; ?>" onclick="seleccionar(this.id);" title="Seleccionar una fila y luego click en Eliminar">
                                <td width="60%" class="nombre1"><?php echo $compras[$i]['descripcion']; ?> <input type="hidden" class="nombre" name="list[]" value="<?php echo $compras[$i]['descripcion']; ?>"></td>
                                <td width="10%"><?php echo $compras[$i]['precio']; ?></td>
                                <td width="10%"><input type="number" class="form-control input al_cargar" value="1" required="true"></td>
                                <td width="10%"><input type="text" class="form-control total" value="<?php echo $compras[$i]['precio']; ?>" disabled></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "No hay productos en el carrito";
                }
                ?>
            <tfoot>
                <tr class="text-center">                    
                    <td colspan="3">                              
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">   
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" id="eliminar" title="Eliminar fila seleccionada"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <button class="btn btn-info calculos">Calcular&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-calculator"></i></button>                                                                                            
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <button class="btn btn-success siguiente" title="siguiente">Comprar ahora</button>
                        </div>
                    </td>                        
                    <td>
                        <strong class="text-right">TOTAL</strong>
                        <!--Aquí va el resultado total-->
                    </td>                        
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Puedes darle una clase al `td` de esa columna y recoger cada valor en el `onclick` del botón con `querySelectorAll`  o de otro modo. Inténtalo y si tienes algún problema nos dices, poniendo el código que estás usando (este es un problema a resolver en el cliente, por tanto, usando Javascript).

Comment: ok veré si entiendo, voy a probarlo y luego aviso

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.siguiente').show();
        $('.siguiente').click(function () {    
            var productos = document.querySelectorAll(".nombre1");
                alert(productos.length);             
        }); //Fin de Siguiente.click
    }); //Fin de Document Ready ___intente eso y no encuentro como mostrar el array pero puse el .length y me muestra que si tengo 2 producto...como hago para mostrar el vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede lograr recorriendo cada fila y despues por su columna, en caso de hacer algo dinámico te recomiendo construir la tabla con `JS`, y de esa manera ya tendrias los datos guardado, pero una solucion como la que buscas sera de esta manera, en caso de que la tabla ya no se mueva.

```js
function obtener(){
  var lista = [];
  var l = $("#tablaProductos tbody tr td");
  //recorres todos los datos y obtienes solo lo necesario
  Object.keys(l).forEach((k,v) => {
    if(v%4 == 0 && l[k].innerText){
      console.log(l[k].innerText)
      lista.push(l[k].innerText);
    }
  });
  console.log(lista);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tablaProductos" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Producto</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
            <th>Subtotal</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Producto A</td><td>10</td><td>2</td><td>20</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>Producto B</td><td>10</td><td>2</td><td>20</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>Producto C</td><td>10</td><td>2</td><td>20</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>Producto D</td><td>10</td><td>2</td><td>20</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="obtener()">Obtener</button>
```

Comment: hola! esto es lo que estoy buscando, pero cuando copio el código y lo pego me da errores en "if(v%4 == 0 && l[k].innerText){"

Comment: falta ponerle `id` a tu tabla `<table id="tablaProductos" border="1">`

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes obtener todas las filas de la tabla, lo cual puedes hacer fácilmente con [`HTMLTableElement.rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows), esto incluye filas en `<thead>`, `<tfoot>`, y `<tbody>`.

Ya que tienes las filas, recorres cada una de ellas y evaluas si el número de celdas en esa fila mayor al de la columna que quieres obtener. Se empieza desde la fila 1, ya que la fila 0 es el header de la tabla. Si quieres obtener la `columna = 4` para una tabla que tiene `columnas = 3`, entonces cada fila tiene un total de 3 celdas por lo que es imposible obtener la celda 4, ya que no existe.

En el código, se hace la resta de menos 1 a la columna solicitada ya que para tener una mejor comprensión, se maneja en lógica 1.

Por último, si nada ha sido agregado al array, la función devuelve `null`. Entonces al llamar a la función se asigna el resultado de la función a un elemento dentro del DOM o en tu caso, se puede usar como argumento para la función que enviará el array al archivo .php.

```js
function obtenerColumna(idTabla, columna) {
  const tabla = document.getElementById(idTabla);
  const filas = tabla.rows.length;
  const array = [];
  columna -= 1;

  // Revisar si la columna es menor que 0
  if (columna < 0) {
    return null;
  }

  // Empezar desde el índice 1 para evitar el header
  for (let i = 1; i < filas; i++) {
    // Revisar si el número de celda no está fuera de rango
    if (tabla.rows[i].cells.length > columna) {
      array.push(tabla.rows[i].cells[columna].innerText);
    }
  }

  return array.length ? array : null;
}

const btnObtenerColumna = document.getElementById('btnObtenerColumna');
const numeroDeColumna = document.getElementById('numeroColumna');
const resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

btnObtenerColumna.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const columna = obtenerColumna('tablaProductos', numeroDeColumna.value);
  resultado.innerText = columna;
});
```

```html
<table id="tablaProductos" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Producto</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
            <th>Subtotal</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Producto A</td><td>10</td><td>2</td><td>20</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>Producto B</td><td>10</td><td>2</td><td>20</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>Producto C</td><td>10</td><td>2</td><td>20</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>Producto D</td><td>10</td><td>2</td><td>20</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="number" id="numeroColumna" value="1" min="1" />
<button id="btnObtenerColumna">Get column</button>
<hr/>
Result:
<pre id="resultado"></pre>
```